# How to choose a future work topic?

Tags: publications

I am currently writing a paper and not sure how to choose what to include as future work opportunities. Based on our work, many other extensions in different areas could be made (which I of course cannot include all).

Is it better to have something very tightly coupled with the current paper or something much broader that offers a lot more potential, but perhaps is a lot more speculative?

Or put differently, what "size" should the future work be? Part of another paper, or more like a PhD scope?

Comment: Actually it sounds like you don't have anything planned for future work and just want to make something up. True?

Comment: I don't think mentioning future work is mandatory in a paper. Readers will probably be more interested in your present results.